# Make node.js program prevent the system from entering sleep mode

Tags: node.js, operating-system, sleep-mode

I am wondering if it is possible for a node.js program/script to prevent the operating system (windows) from entering in sleep or hibernate mode?

Comment: one way you can do it, just fire a request to node js server at a particular interval

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will help you.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/stay-awake

```
var stayAwake = require('stay-awake');

// do something not so important 

// prevent auto sleep 
stayAwake.prevent(function(err, data) {
    // handle error 
    console.log('%d routines are preventing sleep', data);
});

// do something which needs the computer to stay awake 

// do something async 
doAsync(function() {
    // do something 
    stayAwake.prevent(function() {}); // second call 
    // do long processing 
    stayAwake.allow(function() {}); // this subroutine no longer needs to prevent sleep 
});

// once done allow the computer to sleep as configured in power management 
stayAwake.allow(function(err, data) {
    if(data == 0) {
        console.log('Will sleep automatically');
    }
}); // allow
```

Comment: Linux is not supported with this package.

Comment: This plugin does not works anymore with Node 14. (this is my experience).
I think that this is the right URL of repository: https://github.com/dapetcu21/node-stay-awake

Answer (score 1):

I was used "stay-awake" but it does not works in "Node 14".

Now I use this:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-prevent-sleep

Comment: this is not supporting OSX